# How to connect vb.net to x10hosting database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I tried already the localhost database and it works, but when I use the server of the online database it always shows

"An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Connection unexpectedly terminated."

I've already downloaded Connector/Net but it doesn't work also.

Codes:

```
connector.ConnectionString = "server=198.91.81.6;userid=pearlcen_root;password=1234;Database=pearlcen_event"
```

Comment: Not sure but they seems to not allow a remote connection to MySql on their free service plan

Comment: ahh I see, I choose not to buy a host because I will just use it once during our defense. is there a free hosting that will allow to remote connection to MySql?